# Is this a reduced sentential clause?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> The car flipped over, trapping its occupants inside.

Is ***trapping its occupants inside*** a reduced sentential clause?

Please explain the grammaticality of such uses of present participle phrases.

Comment: Please explain your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

> The car flipped over, *trapping its occupants inside.*

The italicized element is an Adjunct, realised by a Gerund-Participle clause. *trapping its occupants inside* is a Gerund-Participle clause.

**Meaning:**

The car flipped over and as a result its occupants are trapped inside.